# Adding reference dll in specific version

Tags: dll, version

I need to add a dll into references of my project in Visual Studio 2019. But there are two dll with same name, same version... each one origins from different software version (different versions of sw I need to connect to). I can choose one or another but always the newer one is used... I need to use an older one... how can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solution is quite simple. Do not use "preloaded" selection of extensions, just manually add dll from folder. This will use the specific one not any newer.